# How to do a reverse char copy in C++

Tags: c++, copy, logic

Hi guys so I am having some trouble with my reverse copy method. The method needs to copy the char* in reverse.

```
char* reverseCopy(char* destination, const char* source, int num)
{
    char placeHolder;
    for (int j=0; j<=num; j++)
    {
        strcpy(destination,source);
    }

    for (int i=0; i<num; num--)
    {
        placeHolder = destination[num];
        destination[i]=placeHolder;
    }
    destination[num]='\0';
    return destination;
}
```

Destination is where the copy is being stored.

Source is copied char

Num is the number of characters in the array

Any insight is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What output are you expecting, and what output are you getting, exactly?

Comment: Honestly, that is overly complex code just to reverse a string.

Comment: Why `strcpy` inside a loop???

Comment: Just get a pointer to the last character and iterate backwards, copying to the output string. Take care of the terminating character.

Comment: Yes, I think the OP isn't aware that loops can go backwards.  I'm assuming this since the call to strcpy is totally unnecessary (even though it is being used incorrectly).

Comment: I would highly recommend using `std::string` in c++ code

Comment: `int i=0; i<num; num--)`  To the OP.  What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @AlexLop. Overachieving, of course.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie This actually causes UB cause it will loop 2^32/2 times

Comment: Pretty sure he knew that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But there are easier and faster ways to do this:
For example why do you need to copy the `source` to the `destination` in a loop?

And what if `destination == source`?

Also this loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<num; num--)
{
    placeHolder = destination[num];
    destination[i]=placeHolder;
}
```

Is incorrectly written and even it was a proper written loop, you would override the non reverted data in the `destination`.

I hope something like this would work (taking care of the case that `source == destination` is possible):

```
char* reverseCopy(char* destination, const char* source, int num) {
    if (destination != source)
    {
        std::copy ( source, source + num - 1, destination );
    }
    std::reverse(destination ,destination + num - 1);
    destination[num-1] = '\0';

    return destination;
}
```

Comment: This is UB, because it will go from 0 to -1, -2 etc. AND it will loop 2^31 times

Answer (score 2):

Would it be cheating to use a [standard library algorithm](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse_copy)?

```
char* reverseCopy(char* destination, const char* source, int num)
{
    std::reverse_copy(source, source + num, destination);
    destination[num] = '\0';
    return destination;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use the std lib. I can only use c-strings

Comment: @GrapeSoda3: You don't have to change to `std::string`, this operates on the C string(s) passed as parameters. If you aren't allowed to use functions from `<algorithm>` then I guess you'll have to reinvent this. It would be unfortunate because there are a LOT of useful [standard library algorithms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm).

Comment: @GrapeSoda3 Just look at the sample code for `std::reverse_copy` and base it on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can always turn them to strings and use source.rbegin() with a copy function.

Comment: You might want to elaborate, technically they are strings, but not `std::string`

Answer (score 0):

I might write that function as follows:

```
char* reverseCopy(char* destination, const char* source, int num) {
    char* d = destination;
    while (num) {
        *d++ = source[--num];
    }
    *d = '\0';
    return destination;
}
```

Comment: what if `destination == source` ??

Comment: @AlexLop. This isn't about optimizing. He only wants to know how to reverse a string.

Comment: Then the behaviour would be undefined, just like with library functions like memcpy when operating on overlapping areas. That's an issue outside the scope of the OP's question. If desired, then the source should be first copied to a temporary buffer and then the backwards copy executed from there.

Comment: @Quest checking that `destination == source` isn't about optimizing. It is about input checking.

Comment: @AlexLop. Kind of both

Answer (score 0):

Push the string, char by char, into a STL stack, then pop the chars off the top of the stack, into a new string.

They'll be reversed.

Comment: This solution uses extra memory.